# Composer revert packages

Tags: symfony, git-revert, vendors, composer-php

I am building a new app in Symfony 2.1. I am using a lot of bundles pulled in using composer. A lot of these bundles have problems with this latest version of Symfony and I am having to go into the /vendor folder to identify the issues.

This means that I am changing the vendor files directly - purely for testing purposes. (When we have fixed a bundle we branch and submit appropriate pull request).

What I want to know is if there is some command like `composer.phar revert` which would undo any changes made to the vendor folder (like a git checkout). At the moment if I run a composer `update` or `install`it does not do this.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the interesting question, but you mean `git checkout`, don't you?

Comment: Yes I do! Sorry, too long using SVN...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`composer install`, if you have kept your composer.lock file, will revert all your vendors to the previously installed state.

Comment: This doesnt work for me I get the error "directory ... has uncommitted changes" which causes it to abort

Comment: Oh right, this will be addressed by https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/466

Comment: You saved my day !

Comment: @Seldaek This no longer works, but I can see that some files where changed with `composer status -v`. I had to manually remove the package and then run `composer install`.

Answer (score 21):

If you used `composer update` your `composer.lock` has changed to. So I make a little trick. Revert `composer.lock` by `git` and then run `composer install`. It'll remove newest packages and download the previous.

Answer (score 4):

Add [discard-changes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#discard-changes) to your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "discard-changes": true
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using the latest version of Composer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 cd /my/project/location/

 rm -rf vendor/my_vendor_to_rollBack

 composer install
```

Comment: works, but there should be a better method for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, none of the answers above work except in relation to versions. I you change an installed version, you can revert to a previous version.

If you just delete or change a file, though, the change will show up in `composer status -v`, but there's no way to revert (even with `"discard-changes":true`) except by removing and then re-requiring the package.

Answer (score 0):

`composer reinstall "*"` removes and installs again all packages in `vendor` directory.